# Artifactory Couldn't parse ErrorsModel from Access. Original message: Not Found

Tags: artifactory

we have problems with our artifactory server since this morning. When I try to restart Artifactory, we get this error:

```
2018-04-16 10:11:11,360 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:27) - Couldn't parse ErrorsModel from Access. Original message: Not Found
2018-04-16 10:11:37,420 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:99) - Application could not be initialized: Waiting for access server to respond timed-out after 90303 milliseconds.  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

Can anyone help, we have no idea what's wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue with the Access application, which is being started simultaneously with Artifactory.

You should fine relevant logs at the following log file: `$ART_HOME/access/logs/access.log`

Comment: Thank you. $ART_HOME/access/logs/access.log is the log I am looking for. Seems like the Database tables are already used by another application.

Answer (score 0):

the error message is somewhat misleading. In fact, there was a problem at the database level. the transaction log becomes full on our MSSQL database. We have increased the limit and are working to see how to reduce the size of the log.